Why can Ethernet NICs bridge to VirtualBox and most Wi-Fi NICs don't?
I saw in forums that some Wi-Fi adapters can't support bridge, but they didn't explain very well why.
So:

Why can all Ethernet NICs bridge to a VM, like VirtualBox bridge mode, and some Wi-Fi adapters don't?


The issue isn't really with the WNICs, it's with the architecture of IEEE 802.11 (Wi-Fi) networking. The IEEE 802.11 standard requires APs to reject frames from MAC addresses that have not successfully Authenticated and Associated with the AP (this makes sense; don't accept packets from unauthorized strangers / impostors).
But bridging requires transparently forwarding frames from one Ethernet-like interface to another without changing the source MAC address in the frame. So as soon as your WNIC tries to bridge someone else's frame to the AP, the AP rejects it because that other MAC address never authenticated or associated with that AP.
There are several ways around this. Here are a few:

The IEEE 802.11 standard provides rudimentary mechanisms for a "Wireless Distribution System" (WDS), which allows wireless bridging between two devices. Every frame bridged on behalf of other devices gets 4 MAC addresses in its header: the original Ethernet destination and source, plus the intermediate 802.11 receiver and transmitter. I say these mechanisms are rudimentary because the standard doesn't provide a way for WDS bridging relationships to be automatically authenticated, established, or encrypted.
Some WNICs support "Proxy STA mode" where the WNIC takes on the responsibility for doing the Auth and Assoc for the MAC addresses of the devices whose frames it's trying to bridge across the wireless link. WNICs that implement this often limit how many MAC addresses they can handle at once.
Various vendors have come up with their own (nonstandard) ways for a wireless-bridging-capable WNIC to join a wireless-bridging-capable AP in the normal way, and then negotiate their wireless bridging capabilities, so that they can then start sending each other WDS-style 4-address frames without rejecting them.

There are other options if you just want to get traffic through and don't need transparent bridging. For example, if you have your client device do NAT (specifically NAPT), that makes all the traffic it's forwarding come from its own MAC address. But it has NAT's natural disadvantage of acting kind of like a poor man's SPI firewall, preventing connections from being initiated from the "public" side of the NAT to the "private" side of the NAT.

@Kobra As you're discovering, SuperUser's format is not well-suited to asking multiple questions in one Question post, and Question posts can be closed by the community for containing multiple questions. Please edit your post to remove those extra questions. You can ask them in separate Question posts.

Alright, I'll ask them on another post, but, if you know the answer, please answer those there too

As an alternative to NAT, which translates both the source IP and MAC, you can do MAC-address-translation, which still allows connections to be initiated from the public side. Some consumer WiFi extenders work this way.
